# Pass array back to Ajax with php and mysqli

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I am currently working on a mini project whereby I have 2 mysql database tables (questions and answers). The answers table contains the questionid.  I am selecting one question and the 4 related answers using the below query in an ajax call, it works but not sure if its the correct way?

I am then passing this back as an array to display on my webpage. The question is being displayed but not the answers, but I can see in my response in the console window the values are there. I'm thinking maybe because the question and answers are in the same array?

Any help is much appreciated.

**php/mysqli**:

```
$sql= 'SELECT question FROM questions where difficulty = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT answer FROM answers a right join questions q on q.id = a.questionid WHERE q.difficulty = 1';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

if($result->num_rows > 0){
    $array = array(); // initialize
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
        $array[] = array(
        'question' => $row[0],
        'answer' => $row[1],
        'answer' => $row[2],
        'answer' => $row[3],
        'answer' => $row[4]
        );  
    }

}
header('Content-Type: application/json',true);
echo json_encode($array);   
$result->free();
$mysqli->close();
```

**Ajax success response**:

```
function response(json){
  console.log(json);
  var quest = json[0].question;
  var ans1 = json[1].question;
  var ans2 = json[2].question;
  var ans3 = json[3].question;
  var ans4 = json[4].question;
  $("#questionBox").html('<h2>Q: ' + quest);
  $("#answerBox").html('<h2>Q: ' + ans1);
}
```

**Ajax Response:**

```
[{"question":"Is this an easy question?","answer":null},
{"question":"Yes","answer":null},
{"question":"No","answer":null},
{"question":"Maybe","answer":null},
{"question":"Who Knows","answer":null}]
```

**Response Direct From Browser:**

```
[{"question":"Is this an easy question?","answer":null},
{"question":"Yes","answer":null},
{"question":"No","answer":null},
{"question":"Maybe","answer":null},
{"question":"Who Knows","answer":null}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ans1 = json[1].question;
```

Shouldn't that be:

```
var ans1 = json[0].answer;
```

Also your PHP code for creating the array also has the same `answer` key 4 times which I imagine means you get only 1 answer in the response even though you've set 4 of them. You'll probably want to change it to:

```
  $array[] = array(
        'question' => $row[0],
        'answer1' => $row[1],
        'answer2' => $row[2],
        'answer3' => $row[3],
        'answer4' => $row[4]
        );
```

Then in the javascript:

```
var ans1 = json[0].answer1;
var ans2 = json[0].answer2;
```

etc.

Comment: Hi cOle2, I tried it but still nothing is displayed on the page...?

Comment: Edited the main comment to display what is being returned in the response

Comment: @Paul'Macca'McGill: Thanks was just about to ask for that. I see all your answers are `null` so there is error in your php code. Are you sure $row[0] - $row[4] are correct?

Comment: The actual correct answers are displayed against 'question' for some reason? But if you change the array rows all to 'question' and the variables to .question;, everything then becomes null?

Comment: Does anyone else have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Anybody? I really can't figure this out. Thanks

Comment: Hey McGill, try visiting the ajax url using your browser and provide us with what you see on the browser.

Comment: By the way, just to confirm what cOle2 said, there is a mismatch between your php output and what you are outputting as the ajax response.

Comment: Hi @LaminSanneh

The code directly from the URL is:

    [{"question":"Is this an easy question?","answer":null},
    {"question":"Yes","answer":null},
    {"question":"No","answer":null},
    {"question":"Maybe","answer":null},
    {"question":"Who Knows","answer":null}]

Thanks